# location.replace() doesn't replace the page

Tags: javascript, html, logout

I'm experimenting for the first time with transition between html pages. I've been looking for the differences between replace and a href when I founded them I chose the second one. I'm building a sign-out button. So when i click on it I need to be redirected to the login page. But I also need to make impossible for the user to navigate back to the home (from the login) with the back button. So in my home.js file I wrote that (I'am working with firebase):

```
const disconnettitiButton = document.getElementById("disconnettiti");
disconnettitiButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
        // Sign-out successful.
        window.location.replace("../index.html");
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // An error happened.
      });
    });
```

while this is the html corresponding to the button (It's not really a button...)

```
 <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="disconnettiti">Disconnettiti<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
```

The problem is: The window.location.replace() succeeds in changing the page and returning back to the login form. But when i click the back button I can also return to the home page, where i called the .replace() function. The replace method should delete the top of the history but this is not the case. Any solutions? Many thanks

Comment: `location.replace(location.hostname + '/index.html')`

Comment: @MaksimTikhonov the home.html is in the html folder. And index.html is outside this folder so i have to move back from the html folder

Comment: You should really use a server side language and cookies to determine if someone is logged in and have that set up so when a logged out user hits any page other than the login page they're redirected, and similarly when any user visits the login page while logged in they're redirected to the home page. While JS lets you edit the history it won't stop users bookmarking the page or copying the URL to visit it later when not logged in.

Comment: I dont see the issue: I mean you check for login on the site which requires it anyway no? Or can anyone that knows the URL go there without being logged in?

Comment: Doesnt this works? `location.replace(location.hostname + '/index.html')`

Comment: @scragar yes, I know. But that's a small scale project, and there's no chance that people try this kind of """"jokes"""".

Comment: @Lain the problem is that I don't want that if a user signs out and he is redirected to the login page, by pressing the back button he can return to the home page (where he signed out) without sign in

Comment: @MaksimTikhonov no It doesn't

Answer (score 1):

There is a basic error in your logic. Restricted area pages should be accessible only with valid grants.

These grants should be deleted when user logs out. So even if you press the back button you don't have the grants anymore and you are redirected to the login page. The same will happen if you try to point to a specific url in the restricted area.

You can use a cookie for example that you set/unset on login/logout or you can use sessions. On each page in the restricted area you need to have the check of the existence of the cookie at the beginning and otherwise the redirect.

Something is working wrong in your application if after logout you can still see things that are inside the restricted area (but you didn't provide code to check that)

EDIT: i saw @scragar comment after i posted my answer but I fully agree with that and not with OP's answer. There are no need for a login page if you don't want to restrict the application. The login becomes completely meaningless if you can access restricted areas anyway

Comment: Like I said that's true but in my case it's useful. This is a site that will be used by few people that won't be interested in evading the mechanism. Also, the site is created to show some sort of personal data stored in firebase node . In each page there's a control that make the data not visible if the user isn't logged (with firebase authentication). So even if someone copy the url of the "restricted part" to access without login, he won't see any  data, so like i said it would be useful. I'm very grateful for your advice and I will keep them in mind but they don't contain the real answer.

Comment: if you read my answer with a bit of attention you will see that I suggest to use that control you are mentioning to **redirect** users to the login page instead of **hiding** data. And this will solve your current issue without the need for extra code

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get what you are saying. I am already redirecting the user to the login page (index.html), the problem is that when I land on index.html the back button shouldn't take me to the page (home.html) where I called the replace function

Comment: if you are not logged in the home should just redirect you again to the login no? Home is part of the restricted are: so where is the issue?

Comment: ah ok yes, that's an alternative way that I will be using. However, the issue was in understanding why the replace method isn't working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give complete url rather than giving a relative path. So if you are serving the page from `localhost` at port 3000 and `index.html` is at root, then you should give the path as `http://localhost/index.html`.

Also, your script must be throwing an error. You should check the browser console first, if something doesn't work.

Hope it helps:)